# What does -n in 'if [[ -n "$name" ]]' in do in Bash?

Tags: bash

I came across this line in one of the bash scripts. I really don't understand the meaning of -n in this if condition. Can someone explain this in detail?

Comment: Open `man bash` and read the section entitled "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS".

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate of the cited question. It is closely related, but the cited question is different.

Comment: Thanks for providing the links. Depending on the background of the OP, reading the content from the early link may not provide a straight answer (I agree that you can google it though).

Comment: @highsciguy, fair point -- I'm moving the 2nd one (*"What do the `-n` and `-a` options do[...]?"*) to the top of the list; hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Execute `man test` to see all options. `-n` tests whether `"$name"` is of non-zero length.

Comment: Note the bullet regarding "questions that have been asked and answered many times before" in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Beyond that -- it's worth noting that `[[ ]]` is extended syntax, and is not fully documented in `man test`. `help test`, showing the bash-builtin `test` implementation, is closer; the [CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS section of the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) is even better.